# How to update a column only when last word of string matches a letter

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to update columns(HostActvTyp and HostPrvTyp) when (HostCd) column last name is matching with last word of the string is "R"
example string for host column "NXVR','REACTIVE', so the last word is R so we have to update to Reactive when it's N' to 'NEW' example "XVDN"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxPbp.png)

Comment: You're probably looking for `ActvTyp LIKE '%I'` -- and I suspect you're falling into an antipattern, too. Do you really need this strange restriction?

Answer (score 0):

seems you are looking for left  or  substr()

```
update tablename 
set ActTyp = 'INDEPENDENT' 
where ActvTyp = left(your_value,1 )
```

Comment: Last word ending with "I" "R" "N"  are unique words..so will this logic works??

Answer (score 0):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bG4jZfnWksjc315eGTuG2k/1

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET ActTyp = 'INDEPENDENT' 
WHERE 'I' = RIGHT(ActvTyp, 1)
```

Or if there is a space separator

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET ActTyp = 'INDEPENDENT' 
WHERE ' I' = RIGHT(ActvTyp, 2)
```