# Update column if the last word string matches the letter ending with "I" "R" "N"

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

```
UPDATE Tbls.Host SET 
HostActvTyp = CASE, HostPrevTyp = CASE WHEN LENGTH(RTRIM(LTRIM(HostCd)))=3 
                                 then 'CORE' 
                                 ELSE END,
HostActvTyp = CASE, HostPrevTyp = CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RTRIM(LTRIM(HSTHC)),4)='P' 
                                  then'PROSPECTING'
                                   ELSE END,
HostActvTyp = CASE, HostPrevTyp = CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RTRIM(LTRIM(HSTHC)),4)='I' 
                                 then'INDEPENDENT' 
                                 ELSE END,
HostActvTyp = CASE, HostPrevTyp = CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RTRIM(LTRIM(HSTHC)),4)='R' 
                                 then 'REACTIVE' 
                                 ELSE END,
HostActvTyp = CASE, HostPrevTyp = CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RTRIM(LTRIM(HSTHC)),4)='N' 
                                 then 'NEW' 
                                 ELSE END;
```

Comment: What am I missing here and what changes I need to make to run this query ??

Comment: Please see this link if you need more clarity on this question:                             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907953/how-to-update-a-column-only-when-last-word-of-string-matches-a-letter

Comment: @DaleBurrell    sql server---actually teradata sql assistant

Comment: sql server and teradata sql assistant are 2 entirely different things

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you're looking for.

```
UPDATE Tbls.Host set 
    HostPrevTyp = CASE WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(HostCd))=3 then 'CORE' 
                       WHEN SUBSTR(TRIM(HSTHC),4)='P' then'PROSPECTING' 
                       WHEN SUBSTR(TRIM(HSTHC),4)='I' then'INDEPENDENT' 
                       WHEN SUBSTR(TRIM(HSTHC),4)='R' then 'REACTIVE' 
                       WHEN SUBSTR(TRIM(HSTHC),4)='N' then 'NEW' 
                       ELSE 'UNKONWN' END
/*WHERE Clause maybe?*/
;
```

Comment: If none satisfies above condition then it sould be 'UNKNOWN'

Comment: Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3706 : 42000] Syntax error: Data Type "RTRIM" does not match a Defined Type name. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.202 
 
STATEMENT 1: Update Statement failed.